# Increase speed of SQLAlchemy Insert.execute()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider following working code of copy a souce sqlite database to target sqlite database:

```py
# Create two database.
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import time

cn_src = sqlite3.connect('source.db')
df=pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2],"y":[2.0,3.0]})
df.to_sql("A", cn_src, if_exists="replace", index=False)

cn_tgt = sqlite3.connect('target.db')
cn_src.close()
cn_tgt.close()

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, event
from sqlalchemy.sql import sqltypes


# create sqlalchemy conneciton
src_engine = create_engine("sqlite:///source.db")
src_metadata = MetaData(bind=src_engine)
exclude_tables = ('sqlite_master', 'sqlite_sequence', 'sqlite_temp_master')

tgt_engine = create_engine("sqlite:///target.db")
tgt_metadata = MetaData(bind=tgt_engine)

@event.listens_for(src_metadata, "column_reflect")
def genericize_datatypes(inspector, tablename, column_dict):
    column_dict["type"] = column_dict["type"].as_generic(allow_nulltype=True)     

tgt_conn = tgt_engine.connect()
tgt_metadata.reflect()

# delete tables in target database.
for table in reversed(tgt_metadata.sorted_tables):
    if table.name not in exclude_tables:
        print('dropping table =', table.name)
        table.drop()

tgt_metadata.clear()
tgt_metadata.reflect()
src_metadata.reflect()

# copy table
for table in src_metadata.sorted_tables:
    if table.name not in exclude_tables:
        table.create(bind=tgt_engine)

# Update meta information
tgt_metadata.clear()
tgt_metadata.reflect()

# Copy data
for table in tgt_metadata.sorted_tables:
    src_table = src_metadata.tables[table.name]
    stmt = table.insert()
    for index, row in enumerate(src_table.select().execute()):
        print("table =", table.name, "Inserting row", index)
        start=time.time()
        stmt.execute(row._asdict())
        end=time.time()
        print(end-start)
```

The code was mainly borrowed from other source. The problem is the time `end-start` is about 0.017 in my computer which is too large. Is there any way to speed up? I have tried set `isolation_level=None` in `create_engine` but no luck.

It seems like that `Insert` object has no `executemany` method so we can't use bulk inserting.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like that Insert object has no executemany method so we can't use bulk inserting.

SQLAlchemy does not implement separate `execute()` and `executemany()` methods. Its `execute()` method looks at the parameters it receives and

- if they consist of a single `dict` object (i.e., a single row) then it calls `execute()` at the driver level, or
- if they consist of a list of `dict` objects (i.e., multiple rows) then it calls `executemany()` at the driver level.

Note also that you are using deprecated usage patterns, specifically `MetaData(bind=…)`. You should be doing something more like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite://")

tbl = sa.Table(
    "tbl",
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    sa.Column("txt", sa.String),
)
tbl.create(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    stmt = sa.insert(tbl)
    params = [
        dict(id=1, txt="foo"),
        dict(id=2, txt="bar"),
    ]
    conn.execute(stmt, params)

# check results
with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.exec_driver_sql("SELECT * FROM tbl").all())
    # [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')]
```

Comment: I'm copy tables so manualy encoding each column with `sa.Column` is not desired.

Comment: You've missed the point: The format of the parameter values for the insert is the key factor in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a solution using transaction:

```py
# Copy data
trans=tgt_conn.begin()
for table in tgt_metadata.sorted_tables:
    src_table = src_metadata.tables[table.name]
    stmt = table.insert().execution_options(autocommit=False)
    for index, row in enumerate(src_table.select().execute()):
        tgt_conn.execute(stmt, row._asdict()) # must use tgt_conn.execute(), not stmt.execute()
        
trans.commit()
tgt_conn.close()
```